# SQL Temp Tables & Replication

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, temp-tables

I have had an issue with our replication process and would like to salvage some data.  I have a process in place where I will connect to each subscriber before flagging them for reinitialization and I will run the below to pull any data they may have entered in during the "dark time".

I am pretty sure this will work in a vanilla palace.  What I am unsure of is whether the `Global Temporary Table` will persist through DB Replication.  To be clear, I am not trying to Replicate the TempTable, I just want to make sure it will still exist at the local DB after the Replication so I may run the `INSERT` from it.

Thoughts?

```
USE MemberCenteredPlan
-- Select Data from tblPLan
SELECT * INTO ##MyPlan
FROM tblPlan
WHERE PlanID = 407869
---------------------------
-- Run Replication Process
---------------------------
-- Insert Plan back into DB
INSERT INTO tblPlan
SELECT * FROM ##MyPlan
WHERE PlanID = 407869
-- Drop Global Temp Table
DROP TABLE ##MyPlan
---------------------------
-- Run Replication Process
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that global temp tables only persist as long as at least one connection using them.  I personally wouldn't want to risk it without having a more solid backup in place,
even if it is just a table you create on a different database on the server, that you later drop.